# Displaying System.Collections.Generic.List does not work

Tags: c#, list

I have this code which I create a list of id's with:

```
var listOfLists = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
const int chunkSize = 999;

int consumed = 0;
while (consumed < IDList.Count())
{
    listOfLists.Add(neueIDListe.Skip(consumed).Take(chunkSize).ToList());
    consumed += chunkSize;
}
```

The problem is when I try to display the list all I get is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

I already tried to display the value of the list with string.Join but this doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you want it to look like? And what **exactly** do you mean by "display"? Console.WritLine? Stuffing it in a winforms label? On a webpage? In the debugger?

Comment: You display type of list instead of values

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I tried to get the ID's displayed in a .NET MessageBox

Comment: You are using wrong                                                                                              
var listOfLists = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();                                              
You must use new List<string>();

Comment: As others have pointed out, you have a list of collections, which means that you still have to explain exactly what you want it to look like. To get *something*, you can try this: `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listOfLists.Select(list => string.Join(", ", list)))`

Comment: Why not just use a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>()` ?

Comment: It's a list of lists, so you'll need to use `string.Join()` twice, for example `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", listOfLists.Select(x => string.Join(",", x))));`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ahh! Okey I see.. thank you for helping!

Comment: what is neueIDListe type? what do you mean by display? what are you trying to achieve? why a list of lists? what is the error that you get exactly and where?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying add data with list but .add is add data one by one. you shoult use foreach() or for() loop for add all data to your list or replace your code with this;

```
listOfLists = (neueIDListe.Skip(consumed).Take(chunkSize).ToList();
```

or if you want to append of your old list;

`listOfLists += (neueIDListe.Skip(consumed).Take(chunkSize).ToList();`

and you can try this for list definition but I dont know if it is works;

`IEnumerable<string> listOfLists = new List<string>();`

Comment: I see that the `List<T>` type does not support the `+=` operator.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You should add with a for or foreach loop. add your data one by one but there is another way to do this; you can use .AddRange   ----listOfLists.AddRange((neueIDListe.Skip(consumed).Take(chunkSize).ToList());----

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
var listOfLists = new List<string>();
```

instead of

```
var listOfLists = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
```

Comment: Once I have power of down voting answers, I will make sure will do the same. People are just downvoting answers to increase their rankings and not letting help people who want to help. What wrong in this answer whoever is downvoted